# OverlayFS CVE-2021-3493 Patch

Tags: kernel, patch, vulnerability, overlayfs

I am unable to patch OverlayFS vulnerability (CVE-2021-3493). They said in github that it is patched in 5.11 kernel however i have installed multiple kernels (5.11,5.15,6.2 etc) and also compiled from patched source code but i am just unable to patch the vulnerability. Can somebody help me regarding this matter? Whether i am missing some step or it is not patched yet?

Comment: How do you verify that it's not patched?

Comment: I can still exploit the vulnerability in the updated kernel and can access the root permissions without being root

Comment: "and can access the root permissions without being root" ... How exactly do you do that?

Comment: You've not provided details as to what Ubuntu product & release, however if you look at https://ubuntu.com/security/cves?q=CVE-2021-3493 you'll note which releases are **not** impated & those which have fixed... chances are your system has been patched already (*if you're using a supported release of Ubuntu*)

Comment: File a bug report to Ubuntu security team.

Comment: I did on ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04 (both versions) and various kernels as mentioned in the questions